# Can PowerBI used to make reports from multiple SAP-BW cubes?

Tags: powerbi, sap-bw

I am getting an error when I try to select multiple characteristics from multiple cubes, I am not sure if this is a supported scenario that PowerBI can connect to SAP-BW and can be used to fetch multiple characteristics from different cubes.

Is that possible or do we need to make a single cube for all the characteristics?

Comment: You can blend data from multiple cubes. [Edit] your question to show your code, and the error you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the wizard to define one query to connect to one cube a time to get dimension characteristics and measures into one Power BI data model, and then repeat that through other queries. This way, you have multiple queries in Power BI to mash up with.

Within the same Query wizard, you cannot cross multiple cubes, because it's invalid MDX query.